# How come Get-Module X shows something, but Get-Module X -ListAvailable does not?

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-module

Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\DevOps\DFDeploymentSmokeTests [master ≡]> get-module xyz.PS.Dev -ListAvailable | ft -AutoSize
C:\xyz\DevOps\DFDeploymentSmokeTests [master ≡]> get-module xyz.PS.Dev | ft -AutoSize

ModuleType Version     Name            ExportedCommands
---------- -------     ----            ----------------
Manifest   1.0.19107.2 xyz.PS.Dev {Add-OctopusChannelsToProjectSteps, Add-OctopusEnvironmentsToProjectSteps, Add-VisualStudioToPath, Copy-OctopusVariables...}


C:\xyz\DevOps\DFDeploymentSmokeTests [master ≡]>
```

Anyone?

**EDIT 1**

```
C:\> Get-Help Get-Module -Parameter ListAvailable

-ListAvailable

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           Available, PsSession, CimSession
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     false    

C:\>
```

Comment: please run `Get-Help Get-Module -Parameter ListAvailable` and read the help that is shown ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - **EDIT 1**. Still do not get it.

Comment: The description from the `Get-Help` command provided by Lee_Dailey that seems to be missing from your edit: "Indicates that this cmdlet gets all installed modules. Get-Module gets modules in paths listed in the PSModulePath environment variable. Without this parameter, Get-Module gets only the modules that are both listed in
    the PSModulePath environment variable, and that are loaded in the current session. ListAvailable does not return information about modules that are not found in the PSModulePath environment variable, even if those
    modules are loaded in the current session."

Comment: Hmm, somehow my local help does not show this text.

Comment: @mark - as OwainEsau showed, the help text _should_ make it clear why there is a difference. since your does NOT show that info, you may need to update your help files OR update your modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the helpful information provided by [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) and [Owain Esau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7287932/owain-esau) in the comments:

- `Get-Module -ListAvailable` lists all modules *available* in *standard locations* - irrespective of whether these modules are currently loaded or not.

  - These [standard locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#module-and-dsc-resource-locations-and-psmodulepath) are the directories listed in the `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable that PowerShell either creates on demand or adds missing entries to; modules located in these directories are loaded automatically, on demand when their commands are accessed, assuming the `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` is unset (the default); see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#psmoduleautoloadingpreference) for details.
- `Get-Module` by itself lists all *currently loaded modules*.

It follows that **`Get-Module -ListAvailable` is not a true superset of `Get-Module` in that it doesn't list those among the currently loaded modules that were loaded from *nonstandard locations***; to quote the [`Get-Module` help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module):

> `ListAvailable` does not return information about modules that are not found in the `PSModulePath` environment variable, even if those modules are loaded in the current session.